# Unable to comprehend the difference and effect of break

Tags: python, break

I wrote the following code in Python to get the prime factors of a number. It gives correct output with break but not without using the break statement. I'm unable to understand why the output is like how it is if I don't use break

```
prime_list = []
def get_prime_factors(num):

    for i in range(2,num+1):
        if num%i == 0:
            prime_list.append(i)
            num = num // i
            get_prime_factors(num)
            **break**
    else:
        print(prime_list)

get_prime_factors(21)

#Output with break:
[3, 7]

#Output without break:
[3, 7]
[3, 7]
[3, 7, 7]
[3, 7, 7]
```

Comment: By removing the `break`, each recursive call will hit the `else` part and `print`

Comment: I'm sorry, but the intendation of `else` part doesn't make any sense.